# cannot find command added to Path - sail_align

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, paths

I'm trying to build `sail_align` programm by following [these](https://github.com/nassosoassos/sail_align) instructions. So far everything went OK and I've completed the last fourth step without errors:

```
4) sudo ./Build install
This command will install the module. 
The following perl scripts will be added to your path: sail_align, sail_align_parallel
```

However, when I run the following to test the installation:

```
sail_align -i support/data/timit_5.wav -t support/data/timit_5.txt \ 
-w support/test/local -e timit_sample_test -c config/timit_alignment.cfg
```

I get the message that sail_align command not found. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the script of `Build` file:

```
  $progname = basename($0);
  $orig_dir = Cwd::cwd();
  my $base_dir = '/home/maximus/sail_align-master';
  if (!magic_number_matches()) {
    unless (chdir($base_dir)) {
      die ("Couldn't chdir($base_dir), aborting\n");
    }
    unless (magic_number_matches()) {
      die ("Configuration seems to be out of date, please re-run 'perl Build.PL' again.\n");
    }
  }
  unshift @INC,
    (

    );
}

close(*DATA) unless eof(*DATA); # ensure no open handles to this script

use Module::Build;
Module::Build->VERSION(q{0});

# Some platforms have problems setting $^X in shebang contexts, fix it up here
$^X = Module::Build->find_perl_interpreter;

if (-e 'Build.PL' and not Module::Build->up_to_date('Build.PL', $progname)) {
   warn "Warning: Build.PL has been altered.  You may need to run 'perl Build.PL' again.\n";
}

# This should have just enough arguments to be able to bootstrap the rest.
my $build = Module::Build->resume (
  properties => {
    config_dir => '_build',
    orig_dir => $orig_dir,
  },
);

$build->dispatch;
```

**EDIT**

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

`locate sail_align` outputs nothing

**EDIT2**

running `find / 'sail_align'` outputs the following

```
/home/maximus/perl5/bin/sail_align
/home/maximus/perl5/bin/sail_align_parallel
/home/maximus/sail_align-master
/home/maximus/sail_align-master/blib/script/sail_align
/home/maximus/sail_align-master/blib/script/sail_align_parallel
/home/maximus/sail_align-master/docs/sail_align_tutorial_vlsrp2011.pdf
/home/maximus/sail_align-master/docs/sail_align_tutorial_vlsrp2011.ppt
/home/maximus/sail_align-master/scripts/sail_align
/home/maximus/sail_align-master/scripts/sail_align_parallel
```

Comment: could you post `echo $PATH` output and `locate sail_align` output?

Comment: sure, please see my update

Comment: mmmh! try `find / -name "*sail_align*"` and post where you find it

Comment: done, please see `EDIT2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, program **sail_align** and **sail_parallel** are located in:

```
    /home/maximus/perl5/bin
```

and this path doesn't present in your `$PATH` variable that is used by bash in order to resolve command location.

You can add your path to environment variable: edit your `/home/maximus/.bashrc` and add at the end:

```
   PATH="$HOME/perl5/bin:$PATH"
```

than:

```
   cd /home/maximus
   source .bashrc
```

and redo your command